# SVG symbol won't scale when used in another symbol

Tags: svg

I'm working on a responsive logo and am using symbols to orchestrate all the pieces together in 2 different orientations and am having trouble figuring out how and where to apply the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` properties in order to get this all to work.

First, I have the icon shown in the snippet below.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="101.45993px" height="164.165619px" viewBox="0 0 101.45993 164.165619"
style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new 0 0 101.45993 164.165619;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:#64228C;}
</style>
<defs>
</defs>
<g>
<g id="LINE_2_">
 <path class="st0" d="M0,116.262733h64.452919c4.087685,0,7.401405-3.313721,7.401405-7.401405
   c0-2.980515-1.787796-5.670235-4.535866-6.824181L24.868401,84.211975C13.227364,79.323799,5.654168,67.92997,5.654168,55.304283
   c0-17.315697,14.037147-31.352842,31.352844-31.352842h64.452919L50.729965,0L0,23.951441V116.262733z"/>
</g>
<g id="LINE_1_">
 <path class="st0" d="M0,140.214172l50.729965,23.951447l50.729965-23.951447V47.902882H37.007011
   c-4.087681,0-7.401403,3.313721-7.401403,7.401402c0,2.980522,1.78779,5.670238,4.535864,6.824181L76.59153,79.953636
   c11.641037,4.888176,19.214233,16.282005,19.214233,28.907692c0,17.315697-14.037148,31.352844-31.352844,31.352844H0z"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Seeing that this is the same shape in different orientations I decided to make one symbol out of it and use it twice in another symbol with one rotated and repositioned as shown in the code below.

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        
        <!--  The shape  -->
        <symbol id="crystal_partial">

            <path d="M0,116.262733h64.452919c4.087685,0,7.401405-3.313721,7.401405-7.401405
 c0-2.980515-1.787796-5.670235-4.535866-6.824181L24.868401,84.211975C13.227364,79.323799,5.654168,67.92997,5.654168,55.304283
 c0-17.315697,14.037147-31.352842,31.352844-31.352842h64.452919L50.729965,0L0,23.951441V116.262733z"/>

        </symbol>

        <!--  The full shape  -->
        <symbol id="crystal_full">

            <use href="#crystal_partial" />
            <use href="#crystal_partial" transform="rotate(180, 50.729965, 0)" x="0px" y="-164.165619" />

       </symbol>

    </defs>
</svg>
```

I also have a wordmark I compose with more symbols which is structured like this

```
<svg>
    <defs>

        <symbol id="s_01">

            <path d="M0.002529,32.038837v-5.950779h13.792138c1.396084,0,2.527835-1.13175,2.527835-2.527834
        c0-0.949068-0.531602-1.818167-1.376517-2.250425L4.741876,16.089375C1.839269,14.66425,0,11.712204,0,8.478614
        C0,3.796004,3.796005,0,8.478614,0h10.116883v5.95078H8.481143c-1.396084,0-2.527834,1.13175-2.527834,2.527834
        c0,0.949067,0.531601,1.818167,1.376516,2.250425l10.32648,5.283029c2.833931,1.449841,4.616976,4.364889,4.616976,7.548157
        c0,4.68261-3.796005,8.478613-8.478614,8.478613H0.002529z"/>

      </symbol>

      <symbol id="r_01">

          <path d="M0,32.038837V0h9.815149c4.041198,0,7.317236,3.276038,7.317236,7.317236v3.987583h-6.24915V7.317236
        c0-0.589888-0.478198-1.068086-1.068086-1.068086H6.24915v25.789688H0z"/>

      </symbol>

      <symbol id="c_01">

          <path d="M0,24.710617c0,4.077408,3.254653,7.313984,7.317236,7.313984h2.497913
        c4.160557,0,7.317236-3.726051,7.317236-7.313984v-3.985811h-6.24915v3.985811c0,0.59425-0.428582,1.06761-1.068086,1.06761
        H7.317236c-0.670545,0-1.068086-0.517942-1.068086-1.06761V7.313984c0-0.55822,0.309032-1.067611,1.068086-1.067611h2.497913
        c0.572631,0,1.068086,0.357812,1.068086,1.067611v3.985811h6.24915V7.313984C17.132385,3.540656,14.354653,0,9.815149,0H7.317236
        C2.954653,0,0,3.240656,0,7.313984V24.710617z"/>

      </symbol>

      <symbol id="r_02">

          <path d="M15.744629,19.676758c1.63739-1.390259,2.581238-3.42981,2.581238-5.57782V7.317261
    C18.325867,3.276062,15.049805,0,11.008667,0H0v32.038879h6.249146V21.441956c4.065735,0,7.758667,4.604797,7.758667,10.596924
    h6.239319C20.438477,27.485168,18.819763,23.040771,15.744629,19.676758z M12.076721,14.098938
    c0,0.589905-0.47821,1.068115-1.068054,1.068115H6.249146V6.249146h4.759521c0.589844,0,1.068054,0.47821,1.068054,1.068115
    V14.098938z"/>

      </symbol>

      <symbol id="y_01">

          <polygon points="6.613334,0 0,0 7.245356,20.919827 7.245356,32.038837 13.494507,32.038837 13.494507,20.919827 
        20.739862,0 14.126529,0 10.369931,10.846584     "/>

      </symbol>

      <symbol id="wordmark_a">

            <use href="#s_01" x="0px" y="0px" />
            <use href="#r_01" x="24.204374px" y="0px" />
            <use href="#c_01" x="43.267852px" y="0px" />
            <use href="#r_02" x="62.33133px" y="0px" />
            <use href="#y_01" x="80.662591px" y="0px" />

        </symbol>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I then use the wordmark and icon together in another symbol to make the first

```
<svg>
    <defs>

        <symbol id="logo_a" viewBox="0 0 101.477753 206.342377">
            <use href="#crystal_full" x="0px" y="0px" />
            <use href="#wordmark_a" x="0px" y="174.165619px" />
        </symbol>

    </defs>
</svg>
```

This one works as expected when I use it in my HTML which is simply

```
<svg>
    <use href="#logo_a" />
</svg>
```

So when I go to do the 2nd iteration of the logo, which coming directly out of Illustrator is the snippet below

```html
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 25.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="127.646393px" height="63.614872px" viewBox="0 0 127.646393 63.614872"
     style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new 0 0 127.646393 63.614872;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#64228C;}
</style>
<defs>
</defs>
<g>
    <g id="LINE_4_">
        <path class="st0" d="M41.47369,54.333584V18.537825h10.966087c4.515076,0,8.175266,3.660192,8.175266,8.175266v4.455173h-6.981937
            v-4.455173c0-0.65906-0.534271-1.193331-1.193329-1.193331h-3.984154v28.813824H41.47369z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="LINE_3_">
        <polygon class="st0" points="111.863365,18.537825 104.474541,18.537825 112.569496,41.91074 112.569496,54.333584 
            119.55143,54.333584 119.55143,41.91074 127.646393,18.537825 120.257568,18.537825 116.060463,30.656296       "/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g id="LINE_2_">
            <path class="st0" d="M0,45.052303h24.975779c1.583994,0,2.868076-1.284081,2.868076-2.868076
                c0-1.154964-0.692778-2.197243-1.757668-2.644398L9.636611,32.6325c-4.510952-1.894192-7.445597-6.309347-7.445597-11.201855
                c0-6.709907,5.439453-12.149361,12.14936-12.149361h24.97578L19.658077,0L0,9.281284V45.052303z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="LINE_1_">
            <path class="st0" d="M0,54.333588l19.658077,9.281284l19.658077-9.281284V18.562569h-24.97578
                c-1.583995,0-2.868075,1.284082-2.868075,2.868076c0,1.154964,0.692776,2.197241,1.757668,2.644398l16.449577,6.90733
                c4.510952,1.894192,7.445595,6.309345,7.445595,11.201855c0,6.709908-5.439451,12.149361-12.149359,12.149361H0z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="LWPOLYLINE_1_">
        <path class="st0" d="M62.772579,46.161655c0,4.555531,3.636295,8.171631,8.175266,8.171631h2.790817
            c4.64843,0,8.17527-4.162971,8.17527-8.171631v-4.453194h-6.981934v4.453194c0,0.663933-0.478844,1.192799-1.193336,1.192799
            h-2.790817c-0.749176,0-1.193329-0.578678-1.193329-1.192799V26.725069c0-0.623678,0.345268-1.192801,1.193329-1.192801h2.790817
            c0.639778,0,1.193336,0.399769,1.193336,1.192801v4.453192h6.981934v-4.453192c0-4.215796-3.103455-8.171633-8.17527-8.171633
            h-2.790817c-4.874146,0-8.175266,3.620659-8.175266,8.171633V46.161655z"/>
    </g>
    <path class="st0" d="M101.662331,40.521866c1.829391-1.553284,2.883911-3.831993,2.883911-6.231884v-7.576906
        c0-4.515076-3.660217-8.175293-8.175224-8.175293H84.071465v35.795807h6.981926V42.494053
        c4.542488,0,8.668457,5.144764,8.668457,11.839535h6.970955C106.906586,49.245903,105.098061,44.28035,101.662331,40.521866z
         M97.564316,34.289982c0,0.659077-0.534286,1.193363-1.193298,1.193363h-5.317627v-9.963633h5.317627
        c0.659012,0,1.193298,0.534286,1.193298,1.193363V34.289982z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

The `crystal_full` element doesn't scale to fit the height of the `viewBox`.  The snippet below shows what I mean.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SrcryDocumentation</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 25.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
style="display: none;">
<defs>
  <symbol id="crystal_partial">
    <path d="M0,116.262733h64.452919c4.087685,0,7.401405-3.313721,7.401405-7.401405
 c0-2.980515-1.787796-5.670235-4.535866-6.824181L24.868401,84.211975C13.227364,79.323799,5.654168,67.92997,5.654168,55.304283
 c0-17.315697,14.037147-31.352842,31.352844-31.352842h64.452919L50.729965,0L0,23.951441V116.262733z"/>
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="crystal_full">
    <use href="#crystal_partial" />
    <use href="#crystal_partial" transform="rotate(180, 50.729965, 0)" x="0px" y="-164.165619" />
  </symbol>
  <!--<symbol id="crystal_full" viewBox="0 0 101.45993 164.165619">
    <use href="#crystal_partial" />
    <use href="#crystal_partial" transform="rotate(180, 50.729965, 0)" x="0px" y="-164.165619" />
  </symbol>-->

  <symbol id="s_01">
    <path d="M0.002529,32.038837v-5.950779h13.792138c1.396084,0,2.527835-1.13175,2.527835-2.527834
        c0-0.949068-0.531602-1.818167-1.376517-2.250425L4.741876,16.089375C1.839269,14.66425,0,11.712204,0,8.478614
        C0,3.796004,3.796005,0,8.478614,0h10.116883v5.95078H8.481143c-1.396084,0-2.527834,1.13175-2.527834,2.527834
        c0,0.949067,0.531601,1.818167,1.376516,2.250425l10.32648,5.283029c2.833931,1.449841,4.616976,4.364889,4.616976,7.548157
        c0,4.68261-3.796005,8.478613-8.478614,8.478613H0.002529z"/>
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="r_01">
    <path d="M0,32.038837V0h9.815149c4.041198,0,7.317236,3.276038,7.317236,7.317236v3.987583h-6.24915V7.317236
        c0-0.589888-0.478198-1.068086-1.068086-1.068086H6.24915v25.789688H0z"/>
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="c_01">
    <path d="M0,24.710617c0,4.077408,3.254653,7.313984,7.317236,7.313984h2.497913
        c4.160557,0,7.317236-3.726051,7.317236-7.313984v-3.985811h-6.24915v3.985811c0,0.59425-0.428582,1.06761-1.068086,1.06761
        H7.317236c-0.670545,0-1.068086-0.517942-1.068086-1.06761V7.313984c0-0.55822,0.309032-1.067611,1.068086-1.067611h2.497913
        c0.572631,0,1.068086,0.357812,1.068086,1.067611v3.985811h6.24915V7.313984C17.132385,3.540656,14.354653,0,9.815149,0H7.317236
        C2.954653,0,0,3.240656,0,7.313984V24.710617z"/>
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="r_02">
    <path d="M15.744629,19.676758c1.63739-1.390259,2.581238-3.42981,2.581238-5.57782V7.317261
    C18.325867,3.276062,15.049805,0,11.008667,0H0v32.038879h6.249146V21.441956c4.065735,0,7.758667,4.604797,7.758667,10.596924
    h6.239319C20.438477,27.485168,18.819763,23.040771,15.744629,19.676758z M12.076721,14.098938
    c0,0.589905-0.47821,1.068115-1.068054,1.068115H6.249146V6.249146h4.759521c0.589844,0,1.068054,0.47821,1.068054,1.068115
    V14.098938z"/>
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="y_01">
    <polygon points="6.613334,0 0,0 7.245356,20.919827 7.245356,32.038837 13.494507,32.038837 13.494507,20.919827 
        20.739862,0 14.126529,0 10.369931,10.846584     "/>
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="wordmark_a">
    <use href="#s_01" x="0px" y="0px" />
    <use href="#r_01" x="24.204374px" y="0px" />
    <use href="#c_01" x="43.267852px" y="0px" />
    <use href="#r_02" x="62.33133px" y="0px" />
    <use href="#y_01" x="80.662591px" y="0px" />
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="wordmark_b">
    <use href="#r_01" x="0px" y="0px" />
    <use href="#c_01" x="19.063478px" y="0px" />
    <use href="#r_02" x="38.126956px" y="0px" />
    <use href="#y_01" x="56.458217px" y="0px" />
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="logo_a" viewBox="0 0 101.477753 206.342377">
    <use href="#crystal_full" x="0px" y="0px" />
    <use href="#wordmark_a" x="0px" y="174.165619px" />
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="logo_b" viewBox="0 0 127.646393 63.614872">
    <use href="#crystal_full" x="0px" y="0px" />
    <use href="#wordmark_b" x="85.441093px" y="20px" />
  </symbol>

</defs>

</svg>

  <svg>
    <use href="#logo_b" />
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried adding a `viewBox` property onto the `crystal_full` element to match the size of what's exported out of Illustrator and while it worked for this instance, when looking back at the `logo_a` element it adds a margin to the top making it overlay the `wordmark_a` element.  I tried multiple variations of `preserveAspectRatio` on different elements and it just moved everything back and forth across the screen.  I added `viewBox` properties to other elements as well and it didn't make any difference in the output.  What do I need to do in order for the elements to play well together in this kind of structure?

To help you help me figure this out here's the `viewBox` settings for each of the elements when exported individually

> crystal_partial = 0 0 101.45993 116.262733

> crystal_full = 0 0 101.45993 164.165619

> s_01 = 0 0 22.273281 32.038837

> r_01 = 0 0 17.132385 32.038837

> c_01 = 0 0 17.132385 32.024601

> r_02 = 0 0 20.262354 32.038879

> y_01 = 0 0 20.739862 32.038837

> wordmark_a = 0 0 101.462456 32.038879

> wordmark_b = 0 0 77.128502 32.038879

> logo_a = 0 0 101.477753 206.342377

> logo_b = 0 0 127.646393 63.614872

Comment: `viewBox` on a symbol always goes together with `width` and `height` on the use element. The first defines which part of the source is shown, the second at which size. You code has no size for the `<use>` elements, which means the default 100% will be used in both directions. 100% is relative to either the enclosing `<svg>` element, or an enclosing `<symbol>` if that is nearer. The default size of an `<svg>` is 300px*150px.

Comment: Actually I've been using a height of 90px in my own code on my computer just to make it smaller than the full screen.  I initially left it off because I want it to respond to the size of its parent container when used in my html.  However either which way `#logo_a` renders properly even if at the full screen size.  But `#logo_b` on the other hand is rendering wrong inside the `symbol` both by being too large and by one of the `crystal_partial` shapes rendering somewhere else on the screen out of view.  I don't understand why that happens.